# d3.js Radial gradient not apply to `path`

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to apply a radial gradient to my path. but not the radial gradient apply to `path`. how to fix this.

here is my modified code :

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

svg.append("linearGradient")                
        .attr("id", "line-gradient")            
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))         
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(1000))      
    .selectAll("stop")                      
        .data([                             
            {offset: "0%", color: "red"},       
            {offset: "40%", color: "black"},        
            {offset: "62%", color: "black"},        
            {offset: "62%", color: "lawngreen"},    
            {offset: "100%", color: "lawngreen"}    
        ])                  
    .enter().append("stop")         
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })   
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

// Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", "M1,5L400,60");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8hfm/43/)

Comment: What do you mean by "but nothing apply to my path"?

Comment: The Gradient colors not applied

Comment: There is something wrong with attributes of #linearGradient - if you remove line 20-22 you'll get the gradient, but with no smooth colour transition

Comment: I get "some" gradient by changing these lines a bit - http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/X8hfm/44/, probably not what you're after, but you might want to look in there for solution

Comment: @robjez How to get the smooth transition with this approach? can you help me with  some idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that your problem lies, where you define attributes of linear gradient. I'm not sure what this part of code suppose to mean:

```
.attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))         
.attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(55))
```

so I've changed it to:

```
.attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", 0)            
.attr("x2", 100).attr("y2", 55)
```

These are basically coordinates of how your gradient will be flowing in X and Y axis, starting from (x1,y1) point of element to which gradient is applied to, to (x2,y2).
D3 didn't understand y(0) and y(1000) coordinates, and didn't apply gradient to the path.

I also removed one of your colour offsets, and I think it works now.

[JSFiddle for that is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/X8hfm/47/)

Hope this help